# Does there exist any software in (Tex\LaTex\...) family that is not open source?

Tags: latex-misc

Does there exist any software in (Tex\LaTex...) family that is not **open source**?
Do there exists any software in these branches which is not **open source**?

Comment: All code in TeXlive is open source if that is what you're asking.  Apart from being a duplicate it is pretty unclear.

Comment: There have been a number of commercial or shareware TeX distributions, for example BaKoMa, plus a range of simple text editors with non-open licenses. I'm not sure what exactly is wanted here in an answer.

Comment: There's also [Scientific Workplace](https://www.mackichan.com/index.html?products/swp.html~mainFrame), which is definitely not free.

Comment: I've cleaned up comments here to reflect the nature of the question after editing